# How to use like and % in Hive with backslash in string?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I need to retrieve the records  from a hive table that  has specific string .
My hive table has a column with data like this `firstpath\secondpath\secondpathxyz`

I want to  fetch all records which has `\secondpath\`.For this I am using query like below

`select* from table where columnname like %\\secondpath\\%` but it always return empty rows for me .I tried even escaping with `\\\\` (`like %\\\\secondpath\\\\%`).But this also did not help .

The above query does return me result when I use  `like %secondpath%` but it does not check for backslash .

Any help on this will be appreciated .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slash `/` is not a special character and does not require escaping. Backslash `\` is a special character.

Both  `rlike '/secondpath/'` and `like '%/secondpath/%'` work fine.

For backslash use rlike with four backslashes:

```
 rlike '\\\\secondpath\\\\'
```

Comment: Thanks for answer .It was my mistake .It is not forward slash instead backward slash .I think "\" is special character

Comment: @Rajesh added rlike for backslash

Comment: so why we donot need the wildcards here % can you explain ? or any docs you can point me to

Comment: @Rajesh It is RLIKE , not LIKE, it is using regular expressions. See this blog: https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/slashception-with-regexp_extract-in-hive/

Comment: @Rajesh Regular expressions do not use % wildcard, regex allows much more complex expressions. Hive is using Java flavor regex  In case of backslash you need  four backslashes because it is special in both Hive and regex.

Comment: Thanks got it. Rlike is more likesupport for  java regex I was wondering if .* is required for wildcard here

Comment: @Rajesh Well, if you want more strict expression, use rlike '^.*\\\\secondpath\\\\.*$' - this means ^ - beginning of the string anchor, dot - any character, * any times. $ - end of the string anchor. You better read manual about regexp for example this one https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: Confusing to me was that to match a digit ("\d") with RLIKE, I needed four backslashes ('ABC\\\\dDEF' RLIKE 'ABC3DEF'), but to match a literal underscore with LIKE, I could have either 1,2, or 4 backslashes ('ABC_DEF' LIKE 'ABC\\_DEF'). The sql was constructed and executed in python.

Comment: @runrig rlike works fine with `\\d`: `select 'abc3def' rlike 'abc\\ddef';`

Comment: @leftjoin in a %sql cell, that works, but when constructing a sql string in python and executing it, I needed 4 backslashes. And I can reason why that is, but not the inconsistency when escaping underscores for LIKE.

Comment: Actually I was searching for databricks issues and didn't notice that it isn't  mentioned in the original post, so I don't know how relevant my comments above are.